# Ввод/вывод в конструкторах и деструкторах C++

Tags: c++, конструктор

Когда-то столкнулся с "неадекватным" поведением вывода в консоль из конструктора. Типа вывод в конструкторе добавлен, а в итоге в релизной сборке мы его не видим. Тогда же разбирались и вроде как нашли какой-то пункт стандарта, который говорил о том, что в конструкторах нельзя иметь никаких побочных эффектов. Что позволяло, к примеру, сделать "copy elision" и тому подобное.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой пункт стандарта регулирует этот вопрос?

То же про деструкторы.

Правда ли, что в конструкторах и деструкторах нельзя ничего выводить на экран, или этот вывод не будет гарантирован стандартом?

Интересует именно вопрос с точки зрения стандарта, а не "как реально работает", потому что может так оказаться, что в 99% вариантов оно всё сработает, а проблемы появятся при специфичных условиях.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision

Comment: Как бы выразиться... Это все никак не связано конкретно со вводом и выводом, вопрос надо переформулировать, говоря о вызове конструктора (кстати, ***какого именно***? Все же копирующий конструктор — это не совсем то же (а то и совсем не то же), что и "обычный" конструктор...)

Comment: Выводить (и в файлы, и на экран) можно. И в конструкторе, и в деструкторе. Проблемы могут быть, только с выбросом исключения из тела деструктора (в т.ч. из функций вывода), т.к. деструктор может быть вызван, в процессе раскрутки стека, при обработке исключения.

Comment: Даже если в стандарте это разрешено, то это не означает, что этого на практике не будет (обратное верно точно так же)

Answer (score 1):

Такого запрета нет.

Единственное, что приходит в голову - нельзя просто так выводить в `std::cout` из конструктора шаблонной переменной, потому что он к этому моменту может не быть инициализирован.

Лечится созданием в начале конструктора объекта `std::ios_base::Init init;`.